# Backtracking not getting triggered in c#

Tags: c#, sudoku

I am trying to write a code in c# for Sudoku solver.
But it seems that recursion is not working correctly and backtracking is not getting fired.

When i am trying to debug the code when row is 1 and col is 7 it should start unwinding and the execution should come "grid[row,col] = 0;" execution is not coming here

Following is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
class solver
{

    static int N = 9;
    static int[,] grid = new int[9, 9]
        {{0,0,2,4,5,0,1,9,0},
         {0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0},
         {7,5,0,9,0,2,3,0,0},
         {9,2,5,0,3,0,0,8,6},
         {0,0,4,0,0,0,9,0,0},
         {1,8,0,0,9,0,4,3,5},
         {0,0,3,6,0,5,0,7,1},
         {0,0,0,0,0,9,0,0,0},
         {0,4,8,0,1,3,6,0,0}
        };


    //int a=10;
    static int row = 0, col = 0;
    public static void Main()
    {

        if (solveSudoku())
        {
            for (int r = 0; r < 9; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < 9; c++)
                {
                    Console.Write(" " + grid[r, c] + " ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("OOPs");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }

    static Boolean solveSudoku()
    {

        if (!FindUnassigned())
        {
            return true;
        }

        for (int num = 1; num <= 9; num++)
        {
            if (isSafe(num))
            {
                grid[row, col] = num;
                if (solveSudoku())
                {
                    return true;
                }
                grid[row,col] = 0;
            }
        }
        //triggers backtracking
        return false;
    }

    static Boolean FindUnassigned()
    {
        for (row = 0; row < 9; row++)
        {
            for (col = 0; col < 9; col++)
            {
                if (grid[row, col] == 0)
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    static Boolean isSafe(int num)
    {
        return (!UsedInRow(num) &&
       !UsedInCol(num) &&
       !UsedInBox(row-row%3, col-col%3,num));

    }
    static Boolean UsedInRow(int num)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < 9; c++)
            if (grid[row,c] == num)
                return true;
        return false;
    }
    static Boolean UsedInCol(int num)
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < 9; r++)
            if (grid[r, col] == num)
                return true;
        return false;
    }
    static bool UsedInBox( int boxStartRow, int boxStartCol, int num)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
                for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
                    if (grid[row+boxStartRow,col+boxStartCol] == num)
                        return true;
            return false;
        }
    }
}`
```

Comment: Did you try to debug it?

Comment: Using multiple parameter-less methods that all operate on the same global data is *generally* frowned upon.

Comment: Tested it, the recursion is working. It's something to do with your logic that's not working as you expected.

Comment: @EBrown's point is all the more appropriate when working with a recursive method (unless that data is strictly read only).  The whole idea of backtracking is that you're relying on the state being in the stack, so going back out a stack frame reverts the data being worked on to what it once was.  When you're mutating global state you don't get that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic issue here is as commenters EBrown and Servy have explained: using a recursive method to modify global state is not usually what you want.

Note that the main benefit of recursion is the preservation of state that occurs on each new recursive call. That is, the new call creates new state, but all previous state is preserved. However, note that the only state that is preserved is the state that is stored in the local call frame.

Recursive methods don't even know per se that they are recursive, never mind can they magically know to save global state as they proceed. So when you modify the non-local `row` and `col` variables in your recursive implementation, you don't have any way to recover their previous state as the recursive method backtracks.

Instead what you want is for each recursive iteration of your `solveSudoku()` method to keep the `row` and `col` state in local variables. That way, if and when the algorithm reaches the termination case without solving the puzzle (i.e. it finds an unassigned element for which no possible value works), it can backtrack and try a different number in the *previously* considered empty element.

Fixing your code is relatively easy. All I did was comment out the non-local `row` and `col` variables, making them instead into `out` parameters for the `FindUnassigned()` method (which is the method you use to scan the board for the first empty element). Then the remaining compile errors I fixed simply by adding `row` and/or `col` as appropriate to each method where they are used, and passing the values from the caller.

I encourage you to try that exercise, so that you know how it works. However, for completeness I've included my version of your code below:

```
//static int N = 9;
static int[,] grid = new int[9, 9]
{{0,0,2,4,5,0,1,9,0},
    {0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0},
    {7,5,0,9,0,2,3,0,0},
    {9,2,5,0,3,0,0,8,6},
    {0,0,4,0,0,0,9,0,0},
    {1,8,0,0,9,0,4,3,5},
    {0,0,3,6,0,5,0,7,1},
    {0,0,0,0,0,9,0,0,0},
    {0,4,8,0,1,3,6,0,0}
};


//int a=10;
//static int row = 0, col = 0;
public static void Main()
{

    if (solveSudoku())
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < 9; r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < 9; c++)
            {
                Console.Write(" " + grid[r, c] + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.Write("OOPs");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}

static Boolean solveSudoku()
{
    int row, col;

    if (!FindUnassigned(out row, out col))
    {
        return true;
    }

    for (int num = 1; num <= 9; num++)
    {
        if (isSafe(num, row, col))
        {
            grid[row, col] = num;

            if (solveSudoku())
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    grid[row, col] = 0;

    //triggers backtracking
    return false;
}

static Boolean FindUnassigned(out int row, out int col)
{
    for (row = 0; row < 9; row++)
    {
        for (col = 0; col < 9; col++)
        {
            if (grid[row, col] == 0)
                return true;
        }
    }

    row = col = -1;

    return false;
}

static Boolean isSafe(int num, int row, int col)
{
    return (!UsedInRow(num, row) &&
    !UsedInCol(num, col) &&
    !UsedInBox(row - row % 3, col - col % 3, num));

}

static Boolean UsedInRow(int num, int row)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < 9; c++)
        if (grid[row, c] == num)
            return true;
    return false;
}

static Boolean UsedInCol(int num, int col)
{
    for (int r = 0; r < 9; r++)
        if (grid[r, col] == num)
            return true;
    return false;
}

static bool UsedInBox(int boxStartRow, int boxStartCol, int num)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
        for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
            if (grid[row + boxStartRow, col + boxStartCol] == num)
                return true;
    return false;
}
```

**Notes:**

- You only need to reset the empty element to 0 when the `solveSudoku()` method is about to return `false`. In any other case, the next iteration of the loop is just going to overwrite the current value anyway, and having the previous invalid value still there when you call `isSafe()` doesn't interfere with that method's operation. I've made that change above.
- I did not bother to actually check the output. The code seems reasonably correct otherwise for a brute-force Sudoku solver, but I'm not making any promises about whether you have any other bugs in the code.
- Similarly, I have not commented on other opportunities for optimization here. I'm just providing information for how to get the basic idea to work.